# Trouble defining a composite game for Sprague-Grundy theorem

Tags: xor, game-theory

I'm writing a blog post to explain how to use Sprague-Grundy theorem to solve various game problems, and I'm having trouble understanding myself, how we define a composite game.

Here's what I've got so far:

> Sprague grundy theorem, can be ecapsulated by the following points
>
> - Any position in an  impartial game can be reduced to a grundy number
>     (or nimber), where a  grundry number of 0 is a losing position (that
>     is if the opponent plays perfectly, you will always lose).
> - Any position can evaluated as the minimum exclusive (or mex) of that
>     position's child nodes. Eg a position that has child nodes with grundy
>     values of 0, 1, 3 will have a grundy value of 2. A position that has
>     child nodes with grundy values of 1, 2, 3 will have a grundy value of
>     0.

Now, the next point I'm wanting to get at, is that a position can be split into composite positions, and the grundy number for that position be evaluated as the *XOR* of those  composite positions.

For example:
For a game of nim with two piles:

2 xor 1 = 3, therefore is a winning position.

1 xor 1 = 0, therefore is a losing position.

We can reach this conclusion using the *mex* method:
ie. the subpositions of 2,1 are:

1, 1 (0)

2, 0 (2)

0, 1 (1)

mex is 3.

However, the point of the xor method, is to make come to this conclusion without having to evaluate subpositions.

How do we define a composite position for this kind of game?

Comment: [Here is the blog post](http://dwjohnston.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/code-chef-solving-astrgame-using-sprague-grundy-theorem-and-caching/) for this question, if you're interested.

Comment: FWIW, you might find both [math.se] and [cs.se] useful.

Answer (score 0):

The "composite position" you're talking about is the ["(disjunctive) sum"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sum) of games. An intuitive definition is that the sum of positions is a position in which each player can choose to make a move on any component ("summand") they choose.

A precise definition for [impartial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game) games (where the moves available don't depend on the player, just whose turn it is) like nim would be that if *G* and *H* are positions, then the set of positions you can move to from *G*+*H* is the union of the sets *A* and *B* where *A* is the set of all *g*+*H* (where *g* is a position you can get to from *G*) and *B* is the set of all *G*+*h*.

If you're interested in this material and related results, I suggest you read up on [Combinatorial Game Theory (CGT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory), possibly [on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-game-theory).